# CentOS cannot load library liblapacke.so.3, yum can't find suitable candidate

Tags: linux, centos, package-management

I am attempting to run a command:

```
perl bin/smartpca.perl -i merged.eigenstrat.34string.length.geno -a merged.eigenstrat.34string.length.snp -b merged.eigenstrat.34string.length.ind -o merged.eigenstrat.34string.length.pca -p merged.eigenstrat.34string.length.plot -e merged.eigenstrat.34string.length.eval -l merged.eigenstrat.34string.length.log
```

which results in the error:

```
smartpca: error while loading shared libraries: liblapacke.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when I try to search Google or `yum search liblapack` I get nothing.

How can I install this `liblapacke` library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the package for install library `liblapack`: https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/lapack-3.4.2-8.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

Update the URL according to your version of CentOS

Command like:

```
sudo yum install lapack
```

should install the required library

Comment: `sudo yum install lapack` worked for me.

Comment: @con, exactly, let add it not the answer.